# Mesh is looking really sharp when in render or material preview mode

Tags: mesh, eevee-render-engine

When I'm in materials preview mode or render mode in Eevee my character mesh looks extremely sharp I've smooth the mesh already but it still appears sharp...

[image]

When I'm in solid mode it looks smooth like it should be... ?
[image]

Comment: Well, did you turn off the viewability of any modifier for any view?

Comment: All modifiers are applied already

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure what's wrong, then. Would you mind to share the blend file?

Comment: I found a semi solution I copy paste my model into another new scene and it fixes the problem but still not sure why this happened at all...

Comment: I guess it's just a bug.

Comment: Yeah ... Thanks for your response tho ! Appreciate

Comment: How exactly did you 'smooth the mesh'?

Comment: Copy paste into a new file or delete and create a new material

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me after trying to bake normal map. The solution is to delete the old material then create a new one or copy paste your mesh into a new scene